# Getting Error while call a method from adapter class. java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()

Tags: android, oncreate

When I try to call a method from my adapter class, I'm getting an error System services not available to Activities before `onCreate();`

**MainTask.Class**

```
public class MainTask extends AppCompatActivity  {
    public static final String mypreference = "mypref";
    public static String Name = "nameKey";
    SharedPreferences taskcount, currenttime;
    public static int completask;
    long shared_time;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_task);
             Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
       setupViewPager(viewPager);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);//setting tab over viewpager

        taskcount = getSharedPreferences(mypreference,
                MainActivity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        completask = taskcount.getInt(Name, 0);

    }
public void propertask(){
    final NiftyDialogBuilder dialog1 = NiftyDialogBuilder.getInstance(MainTask.this);
    Effectstype effect;
    effect = Effectstype.SlideBottom;
    dialog1.setCancelable(false);
    dialog1.isCancelableOnTouchOutside(false)
            .withTitle(null)
            .withMessage(null)
            .withEffect(effect)
            .setCustomView(R.layout.proper_task, MainTask.this)
            .show();


    Button rate = (Button) dialog1.findViewById(R.id.rate_button);


    rate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            dialog1.dismiss();

        }
    });
    dialog1.show();
}
```

**GridListAdapter.Java**

```
 if(taskvalue==0)
     {
   MainTask mainTask=new MainTask();
   mainTask.propertask();

  }
```

Please help me, how I can access propertask method from my Adapter class.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: paste complete code

Comment: That's a very wrong way to do it. Please explain what are you trying to do? Whether changes in your CustomDialog will reflect changes on MainTask Activity?

Comment: Actually, there is a Gridview over the MainTask class. GridListAdapter is the class managing the grid activity. If I click on the 2nd grid, the dialog box should come.
I can't write a Dialog box inside the Adapter class, since adapter class doesn't have context.

Comment: So you have GridLayout on Fragment inside ViewPager and you are clicking a cell from GridLayout, am I correct?

Comment: Exactly, you are correct.

Comment: I have posted the answer. Try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to create an object for an Activity. Actually what CommonsWare said you shouldn't do it.

You can call that function like this

```
if(taskvalue==0)
 {
  // assuming you have passed context to your adapter. If not, then do it.
  ((MainTask)context).propertask();

 }
```

**EDIT:**
As you said in your comments "you do not have context so you couldn't made Dialog from Adapter". But now since you have passed it, you can do it now from your Adapter and remove this unnecessary casting-to-activity function call.

Comment: Sorry, this is not working.
Showing error, Method call expected.

Comment: Sorry, rectified mistake. Messed up with casting. Now its proper. Try it.

Comment: Wow, it's working.
This maybe a silly mistake, since I'm new to Android please forgive me.
Thanks.!!!

Comment: Yeah I know it will work but if this Dialog only affect the views inside your GridView then consider adding in your Adapter instead in your activity.

Comment: Sure, Thanks bro.

Answer (score 1):

**Never** create an instance of an activity yourself (`MainTask mainTask=new MainTask()` in your code). Activities are created by the framework, in response to a `startActivity()` call.

Since `GridListAdapter` seems to be used in some class other than `MainTask`, perhaps `propertask()` should be a method on `GridListAdapter` or on the activity or fragment that is displaying the `GridListAdapter`.

Answer (score 0):

You can move the propertask method to in GridListAdapter. Than you need to MainTask Activity's context for this method.